# finding a string pattern spread across several lines in a file

Tags: perl, shell, awk

I need help with finding a string in a text.

From the text below

I need to find the first occurence of `/infile` after the text `${SALE}`. Once I find the `infile` I need to find the contents of the following `/fields`

From the example below the output should be

```
all 1 char 178,
zip 170 char 5***
```

The output will be the text between /fields and the next */*.
Solutions in shell, perl, awk would be appreciated.

### script starts here

```
${CHKERR}

echo ${SALE}
badchar ${SALE} - | upshift - - | ssort '

/stat
/padbyte " "

/infile 0 open stlf

***/fields
   all 1 char 178,
   zip 170 char 5***

/joinkey zip
/derived country "  "

/infile /data/retprep/rethold/statezip stlf

/fields
  zipkey 1 char 5,
  state 6 char 2

/derived x 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the smallest one, but works:

```
awk 'f3 && NF {print $0;getline;print $0;f3=0} /\${SALE}/ {f1=1} f1 && /\/infile/ {f2=1} f2 && /\*\*\*\/fields/ {f3=1}' file
   all 1 char 178,
   zip 170 char 5***
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
perl -0777ne '
    print $1 if m!/infile.*?/fields\n(.*?)^$!ms and qr<\${SALE}> .. eof
' file
```

Comment: Same problem as @mpapec's attempt. `perl -e 'print qr/\Q${SALE}\E/'`

Answer (score 1):

This solution works by reading through the file looking for each pattern in a list one by one. Once the last has been found the lines from the file are printed until a blank line is found.

The program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @matches = ( qr<\${SALE}>, qr<\Q/infile>, qr<\Q/fields> );

for my $match (@matches) {
  while (<>) {
    last if $_ =~ $match;
  }
}

print while ($_ = <>) =~ /\S/;
```

**output**

```
   all 1 char 178,
   zip 170 char 5***
```